# Regex to find all addresses

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

Searching in the code of a Google Maps result.
My regex to get an address:

```
Regex re_addressen = new Regex("\"\\w*\\s[0-9]+,\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\s\\w\\w\\s\\w,*");
```

(Searching for all the addressess in every google maps result)

But then I only get addresses that are one word.
Some addresses have 2 words. I want those aswell seen in my listbox.

My regex idea here is:

```
Regex re_addressen = 
    new Regex("\"\\w*\\s\\w*[0-9]+,\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\s\\w\\w\\s\\w,*");
```

But still, only addresses that are one word long.

Comment: I hope the result you try to parse with regex is not json.

Comment: I never fully got what json is.
But if it means that I get (locate) certain information from a (j) script and filter this into a (string) listbox.
Then yes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to parse an html with regex. [Don't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Instead find an API from google, that returns an xml or json and use it. See [this url](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=madison%20square%20garden), for example.

Now all you have to do is downloading this url and parsing the json result with an appropriate json parser. I'll use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for this

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var query = "big bang";
    var urlx = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(query);

    //An optional language. default is en-US
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-US"));
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("ru-RU"));
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("ar-EG"));

    var json = await client.GetStringAsync(urlx);
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    foreach (var res in obj.results)
    {
        string address = res.formatted_address;
        decimal lat = res.geometry.location.lat;
        decimal lng = res.geometry.location.lng;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}=>{2}", lat, lng, address));
    }
}
```